# What is a 'kinematic endpoint' in experimental particle physics?

Tags: particle-physics, kinematics, terminology, definition, particle-detectors

In experimental particle physics, I see 'kinematic endpoint' pop up quite often. I've made an assumption of what it is but now I am not so sure.

Example sentence:

> "This region is enhanced in B->Xu l nu decays, relative to B -> Xc l nu decays due to the lower kinematic endpoint for B->Xc l nu decays."

What is a 'kinematic endpoint' in experimental particle physics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, one can make a short detour to the usual beta-decay: the plot below shows the allowed range of energies of electrons. The maximal possible energy, $E_{max}$, is driven by the difference in mass of neutron and proton (or rather of the original and final isotopes, if we consider nuclei):
[image]
This point $E_{max}$ is often referred to as *kinematic endpoint*.

Your example differs by the fact that instead of nuclei, mesons are considered. The $B \to X_c \ell \nu$ decay is a Cabibbo-allowed transition of a B meson to a charm meson (usually D or D*). The [Q-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_value_(nuclear_science)) of this decay is driven by $m_B-m_D \sim 3 GeV$. The $B \to X_u \ell \nu$ decay is a Cabibbo-suppressed transition of a B meson to a light meson (pions, rho, etc). The Q-value of this decay is driven by $m_B-m_\pi \sim 5 GeV$, which is significantly larger than that in $B \to X_c \ell \nu$  transitions.
Thus, from the lepton energy point of view, the kinematic endpoint is indeed lower in $B \to X_c \ell \nu$ decays.

In experiment, when studying such semileptonic decays, they can't reconstruct the neutrino. The notation $X_c$ and $X_u$ implies they are interested in inclusive measurement of all charm (light) hadrons. How could one do such a measurement? By looking at the lepton energy (or momentum) distribution.

One should remember that $B \to X_c \ell \nu$ is Cabibbo-allowed (read, huge) compared to the suppressed $B \to X_u \ell \nu$ transitions. The two can be difficult to separate because charm hadrons decay themselves to light hadrons.
But if you plot the distribution of lepton energies coming from B candidates, in a proper frame, you will (I am over-simplifying now) see a two-fold structure: the huge bump coming from the $B \to X_c \ell \nu$ and the smaller tail coming from $B \to X_u \ell \nu$. The fact that the latter goes to higher energies (or, as you quote, has higher kinematic endpoint) can be used to separate the two types of decays and measure such quantities as CKM matrix element $V_{ub}$. To do that, one needs to know the theoretical distribution of lepton energies in $B \to X_u \ell \nu$, and count how many of them are above the charm endpoint, but that is another story.

**Addition**: Sometimes the "kinematic endpoint" can also refer to the invariant mass of two particles rather than the energy of one particle. Say, the maximal invariant mass of $(\ell \nu)$ in your example is $m(B)-m(X_c)$.

Answer (score 1):

This [quote:](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.1923)

> At the kinematic endpoint of zero recoil physical momenta are parallel which leads to symmetries in the decay distributions.

If you read the paper it is a complicated methodology of making a hypothesis on extreme values of the kinematic variables, and deriving useful measurable relations from that, so it is a term with the definition dependent on the specific kinematics of the interaction studied, as far as I understand.It is a complicated method for setting limits to decays etc developed for astrophysics as analysed in this [dissertation](https://ecommons.cornell.edu/bitstream/handle/1813/36028/nse23.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y).